# Is it good practise to use jquery functionality to keep XHTML cleaner / neater?

Tags: jquery, coding-style, xhtml

For example...

If I used jquery to append `<div class='clearboth'>&nbsp;</div>` instead of coding it into the XHTML itself.

Seems wrong to do this but It would be interesting to see if anyone else does this?

Are their any acceptable uses of adding in content using jquery to effect structure or style?

C

Comment: In that particular case, you should [use a modern approach to contain floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) that doesn't involve adding additional non-content.

Comment: Thanks for that Quentin, its nice to learn something new :)

Comment: +1 I still used old "clearer" DIVs !

Answer (score 1):

depends entirely on why you are doing it really. Just adding it in with javascript is pointless if its just all static content. However if for example you are creating a block of elements (maybe a div with a image, title and text for example) after the page has loaded like when someone clicks a button to add a new object, then that would be acceptable. However in that case i would look into jquery templates for defining the markup as it keeps it abstracted from the functional code and its easier than appending loads of elements to a div to build up the block programatically.

Does that make sense?

Just my thoughts however. I cant say my way is the de-facto standard everyone should be working towards

Comment: No, it would be for a comments sections for instance, if I had a section with 500 comments under a post and I wanted a clear under each item it seems messy to put a div clear under every item...

Comment: clearing it pretty much frowned upon anyway these days. In the case you described, in my dynamic language (php?) i would just put the clearing div in the loop that echo's each post, thats far cleaner in my opinion than using javascript (what if i have JS disabled? why ruin the layout of the comments section without good reason?)

Heres a link to a fiddle, instead of using clearing divs it uses the overflow css. Far better than clearing, its more reliable (ive experienced weird issues with clearing in the past) and less code!

http://jsfiddle.net/eF5B3/

Comment: That fiddle may not be exactly what your trying to achieve, but remove the width and overflow for the comment wrapper div and you'll see that the overflow css acts just like a clearing div does. So you can apply that to your own situation